# View inside RelativeLayout not showing up in landscape

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm trying to position two LinearLayouts on the screen: one small one at the bottom and a larger one taking up the rest of the screen space.

They are inside a RelativeLayout. I have the bottom linear layout set to anchor to the bottom of the screen, with a hardcoded height in dp. The larger LinearLayout is set to be above the bottom one.

This works as expected in portrait, but I cannot get the bottom (smaller) linearlayout to show up in landscape. Even if I set its height to a very high number. Both layouts look as expected in the Android Studio editor by the way.

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ff1b284b"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/plusZoomMinusButtons">

       -- Removed inner views --

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/plusZoomMinusButtons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        -- Removed inner views --

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

edit: The problem wasn't even with the layout, I found a piece of code elsewhere in the program that messed with the layout, but only in landscape :|

Comment: Everything is working fine in my mobile.... Either I tried your code before and after editing..

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to provide `android:orientation="vertical"` in `RelativeLayout` that you have written in your code. Ok one simple solution is Just change the main `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` and add the weight attribute to your `LinearLayout` which is a first child of main Parent.

`android:layout_weight="1"`

Here is how your Top `XML` Looks like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ff1b284b"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
        >
       //Leave others as it is
```

**OR Try giving `weightSum` to parent and give `weight` that matches parent's `weightSum` as follows**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ff1b284b"
android:weightSum = "3"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="2"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
        >
        //Body
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/plusZoomMinusButtons"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:gravity="top"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Note :** It is best practice to put `0dp` to `height` if you give `android:layout_weight` attribute for memory management. These are  **Removed because it's unnecessary **

```
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_above="@+id/plusZoomMinusButtons"
```

Comment: I get the same problem using a LinearLayout and weights unfortunately. That's originally why I switched to a RelativeLayout.
 
Is it possible that the content inside is spilling out of the layout somehow?

Comment: @TheN33k That may be because of large amount of hardcoded content of first layout. There is two option left for you then. One is 
**Wrap up all with `ScrollView`** so that in landscape mode you can see your bottom layout by scrolling. 

And Second option is **Create Different alternate Layout for landscape mode** for more info on Creating alternate layout have a look at 
[Supporting Different Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

Comment: Ok thanks. Weird bug, but I guess all I can do is move the buttons to the side in landscape

Comment: @TheN33k ok that will be better.

Comment: @TheN33k I've just removed something and added one alternate solution.... If you still prefer the solution or want to know about this... plz try this latest once..

Comment: @TheN33k have you accomplished the task or still there is some issue left , please let me know.

Comment: Yes I figured it out. There was something elsewhere in the code that would mess with the layout in landscape :| the layout was fine.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this XML. Maybe it will solve your problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff1b284b">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/plusZoomMinusButtons">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/eegLegend"

            android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp">

        </LinearLayout>

        <XYPlot
            android:id="@+id/aprHistoryPlot"
            title="A/P/R History"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/plusZoomMinusButtons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/minus"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/grey"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/magnification"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="10x"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plus"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/grey"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sure, direct links without the imgur album:

http://i.imgur.com/vNsQ1PL.png
http://i.imgur.com/1r9Fb7H.png

Comment: The XYPlot doesn't show up and the original problem is still there :/

Comment: replace XYPlot with your class name com.xyz.XYPlot